# Detailed version history for a specific version label

Tags: client-object-model, provider-hosted-app, version-history

How to perform 'View' operation for fetching all metadata values of the specific version using **SharePoint client object model**, for instance here version 7.1

[image]

I am working for Provider hosted app [SharePoint online], so any SPServices would not be beneficial.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below mentioned code to get the details version of specific item from SharePoint list using Client Object Model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;

namespace AccessVersionItems
{
    class Class1
    {
        File file;
        FileVersionCollection versions;
        ClientContext clientContext;
        IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion> oldVersions;
        public void GetVersion()
        {
            clientContext = new ClientContext("http://xxxxxxx/workspace");
            clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("aaaa", "bbbbbb");
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            clientContext.Load(web);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    string path = web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/Issue Report/7_.000";  // it represet list id 7
                    file = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(path);

                    ListItem versionListItem = file.ListItemAllFields;file.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["Defect_x0020_Name"]
                    clientContext.Load(versionListItem);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    versions = file.Versions;
                    clientContext.Load(versions);
                    oldVersions = clientContext.LoadQuery(versions.Where(v => v != null));
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    if (oldVersions != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileVersion _version in oldVersions)
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("Version : {0}", _version.VersionLabel);  // till working fine


                            File f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/"+_version.Url.ToString());
                            clientContext.Load(f, ff => ff.ListItemAllFields);
                            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                            string a = "";
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
    }
}
```

**Note:-**

Please change all server & list details (in variables) according to your server

**UPDATED**

Please replace below code

```
File f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/"+_version.Url.ToString());
```

with

```
string versionItemUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(Path.GetFileName(file.ServerRelativeUrl),"") + _version.Url;
File oldFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(versionItemUrl);
```

& try again.

Comment: Have you got it working?

Comment: Thanks @Hardik for the code, I tried with this and getting error 'The object specified does not belong to a list.' on this line 'File f = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/"+_version.Url.ToString());' where my string is build up like '/sites/dev/_vti_history/512/Global Lib/ARCHITECTURAL STANDARDS.docx'

Comment: Please check updated code in my answer.

Comment: the problem ended up being that an SPFile was constructed in a parent web instead of the web in which the actual file resided using SPWeb.GetFile(url).

So to fix the problem, make sure you construct your SPFile object (using GetFile anyway) in the SPWeb in which the file resides.

**eg.** if the file lives here: \ParentSite\SubSite\Pages\Page.aspx, make sure the SPWeb you are using is "Subsite".

Comment: Did you tried updated code? is that works for you?

Comment: Ok get that, thanks for the update, but still on 'clientContext.Load(oldFile, ff => ff.ListItemAllFields);' its showing 0 count in FieldValues while debugging for any version label, and if I load only 'clientContext.Load(oldFile);' then its shows file not found like error.

Comment: Check the URL in **oldFile** weather it is correct or not.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: I tried, but in vain. Same issue 'File not found'. My main serverRelativeURL path is '/sites/dev/Global Lib/ARCHITECTURAL STANDARDS.docx' and in the loop where versionItemUrl I get '/sites/dev/Global Lib/_vti_history/130560/Global Lib/ARCHITECTURAL STANDARDS.docx' from this I tried removing 'Global Lib' i.e the library name and made the versionItemUrl to '/sites/dev/_vti_history/130560/Global Lib/ARCHITECTURAL STANDARDS.docx' which also did not work.

Comment: Can you please provide your _vti_history containing URL, for some sample reference ?

Comment: File file = clientcontext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dev/_vti_history/130560/Global Lib/ARCHITECTURAL STANDARDS.docx'); clientcontext.Load(file); _This are the two line of my exact code where I get  File not found_

Comment: As per some more research, it shows that for CSOM, you can download that specific version document ...but cannot retrieve that metatdata details.

Comment: You can get the details but you can not update the metadata details

Comment: Same code works for me as I tried it on my server

Comment: I used the code provided by you (stated below), but while debugging the count of 'ListItemAllFields' for the oldFile is coming as null although its not giving any error. it should show all the metadata associated with it.(I am using the approach shared by you on jun 9, 2016)
*** I need to move the documents to another library along with version history in SharePoint Online. Please suggest. (string versionItemUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(Path.GetFileName(file.ServerRelativeUrl),"") + _version.Url; File oldFile = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(versionItemUrl);)

Answer (score 0):

```
#region Using Directives

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

using System.Net;

#endregion

namespace SharePointClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string srcUrl = "https://aaa/bbb/ccc/";
            string destUrl = "https://aaa/bbb/ddd/";;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("aaa", "ccc", "vvvv");

            string srcLibrary = "MySrc Library";
            string destLibrary = "MyDest Library";

            //copy latest full version of file
            CopyDocuments(srcUrl, destUrl, srcLibrary, destLibrary, credentials);      
        }

        #region Supporting Methods


        public static void CopyDocuments(string srcUrl, string destUrl, string srcLibrary, string destLibrary, System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials)
        {
            // set up the src client
            using (SP.ClientContext srcContext = new SP.ClientContext(srcUrl))
            {
                // set up the destination 
                using (SP.ClientContext destContext = new SP.ClientContext(destUrl))
                {
                    srcContext.Credentials = credentials;
                    destContext.Credentials = credentials;

                    // get the source web
                    SP.Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;                   
                    SP.List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(srcLibrary);
                    // SP.CamlQuery query = SP.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(5);
                    //
                    SP.CamlQuery query = new SP.CamlQuery();     
                    query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ICD_x0020_ID' /><Value Type='Text'>6382</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

                    SP.ListItemCollection srcItems = srcList.GetItems(query);
                    srcContext.Load(srcItems);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // get the destination web
                    SP.Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
                    destContext.Load(destWeb);
                    destContext.ExecuteQuery();                    

                    foreach (var item in srcItems)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (item.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.File)
                            {
                                // get the first file version
                                SP.File file = item.File;
                                SP.FileVersionCollection versions = file.Versions;
                                srcContext.Load(versions);
                                srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                //SP.FileVersion firstVersion = versions.OrderBy(L => L.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                                SP.FileVersion firstVersion = versions.OrderBy(L => L.ID).Last();
                                //
                                foreach (SP.FileVersion _version in versions)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Version :{0}\t", _version.VersionLabel);
                                }

                                //
                                if (destContext.HasPendingRequest)
                                    destContext.ExecuteQuery();

                                string filePath = Path.Combine(@srcUrl, firstVersion.Url).Replace(" ", "%20");
                                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                                // build new location url
                                string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "%20") + "/" + fileName;

                                WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
                                client.Credentials = credentials;

                                using (Stream fileRef = client.OpenRead(filePath))
                                {
                                    SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileRef, true);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("File Error = " + ex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }




        #endregion
    }
}
```